# scanf hexadecimal to uint8_t in C

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I have to emulate a simple assembly language. I have a memory of 256 bytes that I chose to represent by a table of `uint8_t` (as they are bytes): `RAM[256]`.

My problem is that I need to enter the code in hexadecimal so I have lines  such as:

```
scanf("%02X", &RAM [arg]);
```

or

```
scanf("%02X", &RAM[RAM[arg]]);
```

depending on the level of indirection.

Not only this generates warnings:

> format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}’

but it also 'erases' 4 bytes at a time in my RAM.
I guess the %02X format is not the right choice here but I could not find any other way to enter hexadecimal.

`scanf("%" SCNx8, size);` works fine but now I have to read the code from a file, the file is in hexadecimal again, all values separated either by spaces or newlines.

I tried  `lu = fscanf(prog, "%" SCNx8, size);` but I get the following warning now:

> format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>
> ```
> lu = fscanf(prog, "%" SCNx8, size);
> ```

Comment: Note that `uint8_t` is not a byte in C standard but `char` is. (but if your emulate system say 8 bit is size of byte `unit8_t` is a good type)

Comment: @Stargateur well, `uint8_t` is a byte, if it exists.

Comment: The duplicate as it is, except the lowercase `u` you'd replace with `x`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Do you suppose that byte is always 8 bit ? This is false in C standard, byte is `CHAR_BIT` and can't be less than 8. `uint8_t` is an octet not a byte.

Comment: I said: whenever it exists, **`uint8_t` is a byte**. I didn't say that a byte is always 8 bits.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ... you got me :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct format specifier for this case is:

```
scanf("%" SCNu8, &RAM[i])
```

Because ultimately you are reading an `uint8_t` type variable.

For this to be successful you need to include the header `<inttypes.h>`.

For hexadecimal the format specifier will be `SCNx8`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried both :
scanf("%" SCNx8, &RAM[i])
and
scanf("%SCNx8", &RAM[i])

either way, I get warnings :
for the first :

warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format

and for the second :

format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}’

Comment: @Tchae.: Included header? And also type is `uint8_t`? First one will be the right way though. Second one is wrong

Comment: My includes are as follows :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

I use GCC -Wall

Comment: The full warning is acatually :

cx25.0.c:127:10: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%", SCNx8, &RAM[arg]);
          ^
cx25.0.c:127:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Comment: @Tchae.: It would be `scanf("%" SCNx8, &RAM[arg]);` there is no comma.

Comment: From another post (recommended by  Antti Haapala ?) I tried to use the function sscanf (of which I've never heard before) instead of scanf.
Warnings are gone for now, I'll check the effects on my code.

Comment: No comma works too with scanf, my mistake, sorry !
Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work just fine, thank you all.
As it's a marked exercise I will have to explain and justify my choice of SCNx8, would you have any clue where I could find documentation on this matter ?

Comment: @Tchae.: I actually checked it there.http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dinkum_en_c99%2Finttypes.html  I am not sure where to find it in doc form. If I find I will let you know.